# What mapping for this addition to a grails project to ensure deletions cascade?

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to add the ability for users to group together certain Skills in a skills database.

That is, if I have Skill objects in the database as "C++ Programmer" "C++ Developer" and "C++"

I have the ability already to get rid of "C++ Programmer" and "C++ Developer" and reduce that down to only "C++" in the skills database. This happens by going through all the DB objects that have the Skills you dont want associated with them, setting the Skill to, say the "C++" Skill object, and then deleting the Skill objects we're not trying to keep.

I would like to keep a record of this, so that the skill "C++" knows that the old skills "C++ Programmer" and "C++ Developer" were mapped to it.

I created a SkillMapping domain object that would hold the names of those objects that are associated to a Skill. so in class Skill I added

```
static hasMany = [mappedSkills:SkillMapping]
```

And in class SkillMapping I added

```
static belongsTo[skill:Skill]
```

What I want to ensure is that if somone deletes the actual Skill, say "C++", then anything that was mapped to "C++" gets deleted as well. Do I need to add anyhting to my domain objects to make sure this happens?

Comment: What happened when you tested it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`belongsTo` does make deletions cascade: ["*saves and deletes cascade from the owner to the dependant (the class with the belongsTo).*"](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html).

Or get more fine-grained control with [cascade mapping DSL](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/cascade.html):